# json API data extraction

Tags: python, json, api, extract

I'm having trouble pulling data from json API.  I'm trying to get "Total_allele_count".  I'm able to pull other data from the API but when it comes to "exac" data it's not working.

```
 "alterations" : [
      {
         "Gene_position" : "3164,,,",
         "exac" : {
            "close_matches" : [],
            "exact_matches" : [
               {
                  "exac_allele" : [
                     {
                        "West_allele_count" : 0,
                        "Total_allele_count" : "52413,1",
                        "Male_allele_count" : "11142,0"
```

Here is where it's failing.  Am i over looking something?

```
row = alter(data, 'exac', 'Total_allele_count', row)
```

my method

```
def alter(source, org, allele, fileRow):
    try:
        toAppend = [int(x) for x in source['alterations'][0][org]['exact_matches'][0][allele].split('/')]
        #fileRow.append(str(len(toAppend)))
        fileRow.append(toAppend[1]/sum(toAppend))
    except:
        fileRow.append('N/A')
    return fileRow
```

Comment: Your json is incomplete.

Comment: "not working" is not well-defined enough to provide an analysis.  When you say "Here is where it's failing".. are you sure?  How do you know?  I'm suspecting the bare `except:` is hiding some interesting traceback that could be used to discover what is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to write a lookup function that does error reporting, so that you know you haven't missed a level. Something like:

```
def lookup(json, *path):
    if not path:
        return json

    first = path[0]
    rest = path[1:]

    try:
        sub_json = json[first]
    except (TypeError, LookupError) as e:
        raise ValueError("Failed to look up %r in %s" % (first, json))
    return lookup(sub_json, *rest)
```

then you can implement your `alter` as:

```
def alter(source, org, allele, fileRow):
    value = lookup(source, 'alterations', 0, org, 'exact_matches', 0, allele)
    try:
        toAppend = value.split('/')
        fileRow.append(toAppend[1]/sum(toAppend))
    except:
        fileRow.append('N/A')
    return fileRow
```

with the above, and closing your data:

```
data = { "alterations" : [
      {
         "Gene_position" : "3164,,,",
         "exac" : {
            "close_matches" : [],
            "exact_matches" : [
               {
                  "exac_allele" : [
                     {
                        "West_allele_count" : 0,
                        "Total_allele_count" : "52413,1",
                        "Male_allele_count" : "11142,0"
                        }]}]}}]}
```

we can call `alter`:

```
alter(data, 'exac', 'Total_allele_count', '')
```

and get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 35, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 32, in alter
  File "<stdin>", line 27, in lookup
  File "<stdin>", line 27, in lookup
  File "<stdin>", line 27, in lookup
  File "<stdin>", line 27, in lookup
  File "<stdin>", line 27, in lookup
  File "<stdin>", line 26, in lookup
ValueError: Failed to look up 'Total_allele_count' in {'exac_allele': [{'Total_allele_count': '52413,1', 'Male_allele_count': '11142,0', 'West_allele_count': 0}]}
```

which tells us that

```
lookup(source, 'alterations', 0, org, 'exact_matches', 0, allele)
```

is missing a level, before the last one, and it should be:

```
lookup(source, 'alterations', 0, org, 'exact_matches', 0, 'exac_allele', allele)
```

running that, we get the following exception:

```
ValueError: Failed to look up 'Total_allele_count' in [{'Total_allele_count': '52413,1', 'Male_allele_count': '11142,0', 'West_allele_count': 0}]
```

if you look carefully, the value is a list and the key is a string, so the final solution is then:

```
lookup(source, 'alterations', 0, org, 'exact_matches', 0, 'exac_allele', 0, allele)
```

Answer (score 0):

How's about:

`toAppend = [int(x) for x in source['alterations'][0][org]['exact_matches'][0]['exac_allele'][0][allele].split('/')]`

(i'm guessing this is just a straight up defect / bug and not really misunderstanding the json structure)

you should also remove the bare except (as @thebjorn elludes to in a comment) because it's likely masking this error (and probably others).